# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

I am still waiting for a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the answer because, beside certain historical aspects which were already mentioned in other answers, the answer you posted consisted of speculation which not only seemed unfounded, but could even be seen as discriminatory. This applies in particular to the section titled "Genetics".